# howto redirect tty in a gdb/gdbserver setup

Tags: debugging, redirect, ssh, gdb, gdbserver

I have a remote debugging setup with gdb (on a `host` machine) and a gdbserver (on a `target` machine).

The gdb command I am using is something like

```
target remote | ssh -T user@192.168.222.111 gdbserver - app_to_debug arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This works fine and the stdio gets redirected from gdbserver to gdb via ssh.

Is it possible to redirect this stdio to a different terminal on my host?

I tried to do something like within gdb:

```
tty /dev/pts/10
```

But this only works in the case without the ssh/gdbserver setup.